# How to select results where it was inserted on X day of the week for the last X months?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, date

I have to collect all the rows in a table where they were inserted on a Monday for the last 3 three months. How would I write the WHERE clause date to get those results?

```
WHERE Date = (wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

That will select everything from Monday of the current week, but what I am having a problem with is selecting a range of Mondays going back three months.

thanks!

So this is the WHERE clause I ended up with that works well for me....

```
where Datestamp > dateadd(month, -3, getdate())
AND datepart(weekday, Datestamp) = datepart(weekday, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))
```

I changed only the part where we enter the day of the week that starts on Monday I added this...

```
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WHERE Date > dateadd(month, -3, getdate())
AND datepart(weekday, Date) = 1
```

These are two separate conditions; no need to compress them into one.

**Note:** run a test on your machine to see which value you get for `datepart(weekday, @AMondayDate)`. On some systems Monday is 1, on others is 2; it depends on the [DATEFIRST configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).

**Update:**

Thanks to [ErikE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57611/erike) for the clever trick that overcomes the weekday numbers issue:

```
WHERE Date > dateadd(month, -3, getdate())
AND datepart(weekday, Date) = datepart(weekday, '2012-11-25')
```

Comment: Just do `datepart(weekday, DateColumn) = datepart(weekday, 'KnownMondayDate')`